# How to insert values for Identity column directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to insert values into the database through this UI. Below is the code. Now I want the ID column to take values directly (its the primary key & I have also set Identity on that column). Next, all the other values should be inserted into the corresponding columns in the database. Rt now whats happening is, the value from the Name textbox goes to the ID column & it sort of results in an off-by-one error. How can I acheive what I want?

[image]

```
  protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        string strQuery = "Insert into AUser values ('"+ txtName.Text +"', '"+ txtEmailAddress.Text +"', '"+txtPassword.Text +"', '"+ ddlMobile.Text +"', '"+ ddlMobile.Text +"', '"+ txtMobileNumber.Text +"' )";
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery,con);
        con.Open();
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: On a side note, please stop using inline parameters. Try using database parameters, otherwise you will get SQL Injection.

Comment: did not understand...

Comment: Check this out: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Without parameters someone could type something similar to "); DELETE * FROM AUser;" into the phone number field which would remove all users from the system.

Comment: Ok I get your point but what do you mean by parameters here?

Comment: never mind, got it...

Answer (score 3):

**Newer write code like that!**

Always use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This code is open for an *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);      
string strQuery = "Insert into AUser(Name, Email, Password, CountryCode, Mobile, MobileNumber) values (@Name, @EmailAddress, @Password, @Mobile, @MobileNumber)";
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", ddlMobile.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", txtMobileNumber.Text);
con.Open();
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

*BTW*, you are adding `ddlMobile.Text` twice to your string command. That might be wrong using.

You are not using `CountryCode` column also..

Answer (score 2):

You should structure your sql statement like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

where values shall be populated via SQL Parameters.

Also, if you want to take values directly in ID column, why did you set it as Auto in first place?

Answer (score 1):

Your query must be like this

```
 string strQuery = "Insert into AUser(Name,Email,Password,CountryCode,Mobile) values ('"+ txtName.Text +"', '"+ txtEmailAddress.Text +"', '"+txtPassword.Text +"', '"+ ddlMobile.Text +"', '"+ ddlMobile.Text +"', '"+ txtMobileNumber.Text +"' )";
```

Comment: No, it "must" not. It is a solution under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you should always name your fields in an insert clause :

```
string strQuery = "Insert into AUser(name,email,password,countrycode,mobile) values ('"+ txtName.Text +"', '"+ txtEmailAddress.Text +"', '"+txtPassword.Text +"', '"+ ddlMobile.Text +"', '"+ ddlMobile.Text +"', '"+ txtMobileNumber.Text +"' )"
```

This ways, if you add a field to your table, you won't break your code...

Comment: ok, thanks... but how do I generate values for the column "ID"?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get that right is to specify the column names in your insert query

```
Insert into AUser (Name, Email, [Password], CountryCode, Mobile)values (@Name, @Email,@Password, @CountryCode, @Mobile)
```

Your sql at present is prone to sql injection attacks.

Add parameter values like this

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery,con);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
...
con.Open();
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Since `Password` is not a _reserved keyword_ in SQL Server, you don't need use `[]` with it `;)`